# Why Spring Boot Embedded tomcat is delaying API response?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-8

We have been using microservices architecture for a long time. The services have been developed using spring-boot.
The services were developed long back using Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE, which is internally using the following tomcat dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
      </dependency>
```

In order to figure out the slow response of an API we enabled log level to debug on Test env, and found that it is the tomcat that is delaying the response by almost 6-7 Sec, please find the logs below:

```
2021-05-28 13:04:37 [http-nio-9112-exec-1] DEBUG    o.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters-[DirectJDKLog.java:180]-Set query string encoding to UTF-8
2021-05-28 13:04:37 [http-nio-9112-exec-1] DEBUG    o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter-[DirectJDKLog.java:180]-The variable [uriBC] has value [<Path_Param>]
2021-05-28 13:04:37 [http-nio-9112-exec-1] DEBUG    o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter-[DirectJDKLog.java:180]-The variable [semicolon] has value [-1]
2021-05-28 13:04:37 [http-nio-9112-exec-1] DEBUG    o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter-[DirectJDKLog.java:180]-The variable [enc] has value [utf-8]
2021-05-28 13:04:45 [http-nio-9112-exec-1] DEBUG    o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase-[DirectJDKLog.java:180]-Security checking request GET <Path_Param>
2021-05-28 13:04:45 [http-nio-9112-exec-1] DEBUG    org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase-[DirectJDKLog.java:180]-  No applicable constraints defined
2021-05-28 13:04:45 [http-nio-9112-exec-1] DEBUG    o.a.c.a.AuthenticatorBase-[DirectJDKLog.java:180]- Not subject to any constraint
2021-05-28 13:04:45 [http-nio-9112-exec-1] INFO     o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]-[DirectJDKLog.java:180]-Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

If you look at the above logs when the call is made to **AuthenticatorBase**  from  **CoyoteAdapter**, it gets stuck for 6-7 sec ( Look at the difference in log timings ), and this is happening for every API call.

Strangely, the other services that are using the same version of Tomcat are not having this issue.
Could someone please help us out to find out the root cause of this issue?

PS:  I know that probably upgrading to the latest Spring version might solve this, but that option is off the table for now.

Adding thread dump taken at the time when the thread is waiting:

```
`"http-nio-9112-exec-1" #64 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe2c800d800 nid=0x519c runnable [0x00007fe3156e6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:259)
    - locked <0x00000000f814e928> (a java.util.zip.ZStreamRef)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:207)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:140)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:118)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextEntry(JarInputStream.java:142)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(JarInputStream.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet.getArchiveEntries(JarWarResourceSet.java:112)
    - locked <0x00000000e35168e0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource(CachedResource.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMapWrapper(Mapper.java:1006)
    at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMap(Mapper.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:886)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:517)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    - locked <0x00000000e80faeb8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`
```

Comment: Just take a thread dump: on linux you can use `kill -3` or use a utility such as `jcmd`, `jvmmon`, etc depending on your jvm

Comment: @SvetlinZarev: I have added thread dump logs in the question. I am unable to get any valuable information from here.

Comment: @adwived did you find the root cause of this issue?

Comment: @RonakPatel Yes I did. You might be already aware that tomcat can be used as an independent app server to host MVC based application, and if you add some static file ( html, css, javascript, jsp etc..) under WEB-INF directory, it can serve those as well.  It uses an in-built class loader that works differently based on certain conditions.  If we add any files under WEB-INF directory, it scans all the files on the classpath ( all classes present in all the jars on the class path, along with files that exist under WEB-INF directory ), then it maintains some kind of cache for the same.  (1/2)

Comment: This cache gets refreshed based on certain criteria, and when it tries to rebuild that cache, it consumes a lot of time and delays the actual API response.  In our case, we had put JSP  under WEB-INF, which was removed later on, and that's how we resolved it. ( 2/2)